# Best Maps API for android with satellite view and offline caching

Tags: android, caching, offline, android-maps

I start by using Google Maps, but I need to show a portion of the map in offline map and Google Maps doesn't allow that.

So, I need an API with two things: Offline caching (small portion of the map) and Satellite View.

Can you give me your opinion about what's the best API for this?

Answer (score 0):

use [ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/smartphones/develop.html) ... Mapping and Analysis tool. It also provides plugins for Android Application Development For Eclipse.

Comment: I look into it and isn't ArcGis a paid service? I would rather a open source solution.